# Why can't I assign a value to an array from constructor upon deloyment

Tags: contract-deployment, arrays

```
pragma solidity 0.8.10;
contract test{

    address[] wallet;


constructor() public {
    wallet.push(0xd8b934580fcE35a11B58C6D73aDeE468a2833fa8);
}
```

This compiles but gives a deployment error (about not being marked a payable function)

Why does this happen fundamentally and what is the proper implementation of array assignment during construction.

Comment: Your code is fine, I suspect you deployed with a value greater than 0. Since your constructor is not marked as `payable` solidity reverts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @hroussille comment - but yes, simply marking the function payable makes this work.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.10;
contract test{

    address[] wallet;   

constructor() payable public  {
    wallet.push(0xd8b934580fcE35a11B58C6D73aDeE468a2833fa8);
}
```